# Rails - how to cache more assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, browser-cache

I try to make my website as fast as possible. So i also want to cache as much as possible.
[image]
Now i got this:
so i tried to force cache the css first:
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, :cache => true %>`
Still its not cached, i got green circle i need grey one.
How to force browser to cache application css file.

Comment: Assets are not cached in the development environment - that would be really annoying. (I'm guessing this is dev due to the `192.168.1` IP). If you need to test this then run your app in production or set up a [staging environment](http://emaxime.com/2014/adding-a-staging-environment-to-rails.html).

Comment: @max This is production environment on local server.